# Right way to show confirmation screen pre-upload in React Uploady?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

First of all, a shout out to Yoav the developer of React Uploady. It's a very helpful library with all kinds of great fancy features (chunked uploads, upload progress hooks, etc).

I have a question about using the asUploadButton hook. Here's my use case: within my app, a user can choose from several places to upload a batch **to**. This is done by selecting a global dropdown that specifies the upload destination. Since user error is a real thing, I need to show them a confirmation screen. This is easy to do the first time they hit the "upload" screen: a state variable keeps track of whether they have confirmed they're in the right place, conditionally rendering either the confirmation component (if they haven't confirmed), or the Uploady component (custom UploadButton) if they have confirmed.

But the requirement is that we show the confirmation every time. Once a user has uploaded a batch, they should still be shown the confirmation if they click on that custom UploadButton again. I tried passing an onClick into the asUploadButton component, but that callback is actually called after showFileUpload - and I want to show an interstitial modal once the button is clicked but **before** showFileUpload is called. Is there any hook to call a method before showFileUpload? Or am I approaching this completely wrong? Advice of any kind is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as answered here on the [react-uploady discussions](https://github.com/rpldy/react-uploady/discussions/198) page:

In your case, I think a custom button will make more sense. In the end, asUploadButton is a very simple component that mainly does one thing and that is, call showFileUpload available from the UploadyContext.

You could create your button component that implements the logic (show confirmation) and when user approves calls the showFileUpload.

You get access to the method using:

```
import { useUploady} from "@rpldy/uploady"


//...in your component:
const { showFileUpload } = useUploady();

const onClick = () => {
    //custom logic
   showFileUpload();
};
```